# Why isn't my if then statement working in ERB?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

All I want if to output "test" if all_day is set to "true"

Here's my code:

```
<%= event.all_day == "true" ? 'test' : '' %>
```

If I just have `<%= event.all_day %>` it does work and it does output either true or false. So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I realized I had true as a string and not a value, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making sure, you mean to be using the string "true" and not the boolean value `true`, right?

Comment: Oh, it's the value. Thank you for asking me that question, that was where I was having the issue.

Comment: Ah, @DVG got here 8 seconds before me. Sorry I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

You compare `event.all_day` boolean value to `String`:

```
true == 'true'
#=> false
```

The correct approach is:

```
<%= event.all_day ? 'test' : '' %>
```

Comment: I just realized I had true as a string and not a value, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
<%= event.all_day == true ? 'test' : '' %>
```

It's probably evaluating the string "true" against the boolean true which is evaluating false and returning an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drop the quotes around `true`

```
<%= event.all_day == "true" ? 'test' : '' %>
```

should be

```
<%= event.all_day == true ? 'test' : '' %>
```